# Custom query in Hibernate repo

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am receiving the last price of a product by the following:

```
ProductPrice findFirstByProductIdOrderByDateFromDesc(@Param(value = "product") Long product);
```

However, now I am trying to pass a list of product ids as an argument.

I have the following:

```
List<ProductPrice> findAllFirstByProductIdOrderByDateFromDesc(@Param(value = "product")List<Long> products);
```

Which at execution throws:

```
2016-10-06 14:41:17,130 WARN o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
2016-10-06 14:41:17,130 ERROR o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = record
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 7207
2016-10-06 14:41:17,148 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = record
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 7207
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try IN

```
List<ProductPrice> findByProductIdInOrderByDateFromDesc(@Param(value = "product")List<Long> products);
```

Comment: This will yeld in a little different result: I need a first record for each price. That's  why in the original query I've got 'findFirst...'

Comment: @uksz sorry, but I would need to see the mapped entities to understand what you're trying to achieve.